# Why does this GET request create infinite loop? (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops, get

First, please look at the code.

```js
    const [currentUserPK, setCurrentUserPK] = useState(undefined);
    const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);
    const [rowsPerPage, setRowsPerPage] = useState(10);
```

```js
    //현재 USER_PK 가져오는 API
    const getCurrentUserPk = async () => {
        const url = '/api/account/decoding-token';
        const res = await get(url)
            .then((res) => {
                console.log(res);
                setCurrentUserPK(res.data.USER_PK);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            });
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        getCurrentUserPk()
    },[]);
```

```js
    //생성된 액션 아이템 불러오기 API
    const getActionItems = async () => {
        const url = `/api/work/view-items`;
        const params = {
            id: currentUserPK,
            currentPage: currentPage,
            feedsPerPage: rowsPerPage,
        };
        await get(url, { params: params }).then((res) => {
            setActionItemArray(res.items);
            console.log(res.items);
            console.log(actionItemArray);
        });
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        getActionItems();
    }, [currentPage, rowsPerPage, actionItemArray]);
```

The problem happens with this following code.

```js
    useEffect(() => {
        getActionItems();
    }, [currentPage, rowsPerPage, actionItemArray]);
```

When I add actionItemArray in the second argument array, It keeps looping

```js
            console.log(res.items);
            console.log(actionItemArray);
```

these two console.log events.

When I delete actionItemArray from the second argument of useEffect Hook, I have to refresh my page to added, deleted and edited actionItems.

I have no idea why it happens. Please help!

Comment: The problem essentially is the one you found. You re-render `useEffect` when `actionItemArray` change, and you change it every time you call `useEffect`

Comment: @Giacomo Yeah but after I delete items or edit items, there should be no re-rendering cause there isn't any changes no more. But it keeps!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"dependencies" (second argument) of the `useEffect` means the values change should trigger "the effect" (first argument)

Inside effect, you change the `actionItemArray`, which is also passed into dependencies.

Comment: Oh wow. I understood. Thank you Hyeseong!

Answer (score 1):

The `useEffect` is calling a function that is changing state: `setActionItemArray()`. Changing state triggers another render which will in turn call the `useEffect` again starting the process over.

`useEffect` runs on the initial render, and then because of the way you have it implemented, will run whenever one of the dependencies in the array changes. So since it is running when the page first loads, it is starting it's infinite loop on every page load

Comment: Yeah but after I delete items or edit items, there should be no re-rendering cause there isn't any changes no more. But it keeps.

Comment: You didn't include the code where you are deleting or editing items, so it's hard to say what is going on there.

Comment: Alright Andy. I'll work on them. thanks!